# Can SQL database trace sources?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a WPF that sends data into SQL DB, whoever download it can send data into a specify table.
Now, is there a way to trace who sent the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say logging should be done by logic of application. If it's all coming from same application (possibly different instances) you should be able to add some logic with logging who did what.

User Ids, names, ip addresses or anything else you need.

I would possibly add a column ChangedBy to a row or something similar, and fill it from application. That column should be NON-NULL so nobody can actually fill that table without this information.

Comment: That's fine because the only requirement is that we want customers stay untraceable.

Comment: well on the level of Network you can still be sniffed. But that has nothing to do with SQL or WPF.

Comment: In what sort of way can it be sniffed?

Comment: lots of ways: http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/